# Re-obtain deleted weapons in Garry's Mod?

Tags: garrys-mod

So, I deleted my Sticky Bomb from Half Life 2 in the spawn menu of Garry's Mod, and I can't find a way to get it back.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Was this something you made and added to the game? Or was it something you added from the Workshop?

Answer (score 2):

### If you added it from the workshop:

- Go to [Garry's Mod Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/app/4000/workshop/)
- Find it in the Workshop
- Unsubsribe
- Subscribe again

---

### If you added it yourself:

- Make sure it is deleted from Garry's Mod files completely
- Close Garry's Mod
- Put the file(s) back where they belong

---

### If it is part of Garry's Mod default

**Option 1**

- Make sure it is still part of Garry's Mod and that it has not been removed

**Option 2**

***Note:** This may take a while depending on how much you have used the game*

- Go to your steam Library
- Right click `Garry's Mod`
- Click `Properties`
- Click `Local files`
- Click `Verify integrity of game cache...`

**Option 3**

***Note:** This is a last resort*

- Right click `Garry's Mod`
- Click `Properties`
- Click `Local files`
- Click `Delete local game content`
- Wait for it to finish deleting
- Download the game again

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

- Hold <kbd>Q</kbd>
- Click the "Weapons" tab
- In the top-left, click in the Search Box
- Type the name of the weapon you lost
- If it appears, left-click the weapon, and drag it under the search box, into the list it was in (e.g. Half-Life 2)